# C++ syntax: & in front of class name in Pybind11

Tags: c++, pybind11

I'm new to C++ and walking through an example of Pybind11 from [here](https://github.com/sorush-khajepor/pybind11-robot).

In `robot.cpp`, Pybind11 is used to bind the c++ class `T800` to a python class.

```
// include statements

namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace std;
PYBIND11_MODULE(robot, m)
{
    /* 
      ...
    */

    py::class_<T800, IRobot>(m, "T800")
        .def(py::init<string, int, ISpeech &>())
        .def("walk", &T800::Walk)
        .def("Talk", &T800::Talk)
        .def("GetData", &T800::GetData)
        .def_readwrite("year", &T800::year);
}
```

Why is the `&` before the class name such as `&T800::GetData`? Is it to denote that `GetData` will return a reference instead of the value? But if you look at the definition of `GetData` [here](https://github.com/sorush-khajepor/pybind11-robot/blob/main/src/t800.h), the function does not return a pointer. I'm confused by the syntax. Any clarifications would be helpful.

Comment: It's `&(T800::GetData)`. In other words, address of the member function `GetData`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen make that an answer